# Referencing in Cleveref with annotations

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

With the `\cite[]` instruction, you can add some annotations to references:
[image: cite with annotations]

Is it possible to do the same with Cleveref (`\Cref`)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining a custom version of `\cref` exploiting the additional package `crossreftools` can almost accomplish what you seem to want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev,capitalize]{cleveref}
\usepackage{crossreftools}

\newcommand{\mycref}[2]{\hyperref[#1]{\namecref{#1}~(\crtrefnumber{#1}, #2)}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
3^{2} + 4^{2} = 5^{2} \label{345triangle}
\end{equation}

Look at \cref{345triangle}.

\medskip

\mycref{345triangle}{some annotation} is an instance of the Pythagorean theorem.

\end{document}
```

[image: custom \cref to add annotation]

As it stands, `\mycref` causes the entire source expression, including the annotation, to be part of the active link; you may change that by modifying the definition of `\mycref`.